# Handle Notification Bidirectional Body Text in the Correct Way

Tags: android, node.js, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a notification service that sends a notification to the client according to its language.
The notification body language can be either **Arabic** or **English**.
It also may have some words in the opposite language.
Let's say that we have a notification template for each language that takes parameters:

English Template

`${Client_Name} added ${Points_Num} good points for ${Another_Clinet_Name} because : done work ${Work_Name}`

Arabic Template

`أضاف ${Client_Name} نقاط جيدة لـ ${Another_Client_Name} مقابل إتمام ${Work_Name}`

When we have a case where we will send an English notification but the parameters will be in Arabic, it will look like this:

`السيد فلان added 5 good points for فلان آخر because: done work عمل معين`

the received notification body will be misdirection
[image_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4t0c.png)

I tried with **Unicode Characters** to solve this issue:

**1**: Inject `\u200f` before each Arabic word.

**2**: Inject `\u061c` before each Arabic word.

**3**: Check the first word in the text and inject `\u061c` before it if it's Arabic.

Is there an official or approved method to handle such an issue?

client-side: Mobile App (Flutter)

server-side: NodeJs & Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Use `\u200f` right-to-left mark (RLM) to indicate RTL text-direction.

Comment: it still gives the same result.

Comment: The device may run in LTR Locale; `android:supportsRtl="true"` may also interfere. There were custom XML layouts for notifications, which would be another possible approach, but I think that on newer API, they were deprecated or removed.